# Changing the margin property on flex boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a "rock, paper, sciccors"-game for a school project. So far, I have just done the html-part, and I am now working on the css-part, before I move on to javascript. Anyways, my problem is that I am trying to make captions underneath the four pictures I have put in, but the display: flex, and flex: 1 0 auto; tag - that I use to make spaces between words in the same p-tag - doesen't give me the wanted amount of pixels between the words. How do I customize the margin between the flex boxes?

```css
body {
  background-color: #aa99ff;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

img {
  border: 5px dotted black;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.caption {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#innpakning {
  width: 980px;
  height: 700px;
}

#tekst {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="innpakning">
  <p id="spillerPoeng"> <b>Spiller:</b> 0 </p>
  <p id="maskinPoeng"> <b>Maskin:</b> 0 </p>
  <img src="stein.png"
  alt="spiller stein" id="stein" width="150" height="200">
  <img src="saks.png"
  alt="spiller saks" id="saks" width="150" height="200">
  <img src="papir.png"
  alt="spiller papir" id="papir" width="150" height="200">
  <img src="ukjent.png"
  alt="spiller stein" id="stein" width="150" height="200">
  <br>
  <div id="tekst">
    <p class="caption"> Stein</p>
    <p class="caption"> Saks</p>
    <p class="caption"> Papir</p>
    <p class="caption"> Maskin</p>
  </div>
  <p id="info"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fast solution put the `.caption` inside a div with the `img`

```css
body {
  background-color: #aa99ff;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

img {
  border: 5px dotted black;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.caption {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline;
}

p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#innpakning {
  width: 980px;
  height: 700px;
}

#tekst {
  display: flex;
}

.gameOption{
  float: left;
  display: table;
}
.gameOption img{
  display: table-row;
}
.gameOption .caption{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="innpakning">
  <p id="spillerPoeng"> <b>Spiller:</b> 0 </p>
  <p id="maskinPoeng"> <b>Maskin:</b> 0 </p>
  <div class="gameOption">
    <img src="stein.png"
  alt="spiller stein" id="stein" width="150" height="200">
     <p class="caption">Stein</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gameOption">
    <img src="saks.png"
    alt="spiller saks" id="saks" width="150" height="200">
     <p class="caption">Saks</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gameOption">
    <img src="papir.png"
    alt="spiller papir" id="papir" width="150" height="200">
    <p class="caption">Papir</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gameOption">
    <img src="ukjent.png"
    alt="spiller stein" id="stein" width="150" height="200">
    <p class="caption">Maskin</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="tekst">
  </div>
  <p id="info"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to changing your `HTML`, I would suggest wrapping each `img` and `caption` in a container.

**example:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #aa99ff;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

#innpakning {
  height: 700px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.box:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

img {
  border: 5px dotted black;
}

.caption {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="innpakning">
  <p id="spillerPoeng"> <b>Spiller:</b> 0 </p>
  <p id="maskinPoeng"> <b>Maskin:</b> 0 </p>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="stein.png" alt="spiller stein" id="stein" width="150" height="200">
      <p class="caption"> Stein</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="stein.png" alt="spiller stein" id="stein" width="150" height="200">
      <p class="caption"> Stein</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="stein.png" alt="spiller stein" id="stein" width="150" height="200">
      <p class="caption"> Stein</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="stein.png" alt="spiller stein" id="stein" width="150" height="200">
      <p class="caption"> Stein</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p id="info"></p>
</div>
```